# Идти учится на программиста или самообучаться?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сначала небольшая предыстория. Мне 17 лет, через 3 месяца ЕГЭ, я отличник и потенциально могу сдать экзамены на очень высокие балы и попасть в хороший институт. Однако меня очень тянет начать работать, то есть вместо фокусировки на экзаменах я активно изучаю `Unity3D` и постепенно делаю свой 2D проект. Могут ли меня взять на адекватную работу, связанную с `C#` или `Unity3D`в 17 лет(18 только в следующем феврале) ? Просто мне кажется, что если я буду непосредственно находится в этой сфере 4 года, которые я мог бы потратить на институт, знаний я получу не меньше, да еще и в придачу опыт работы. И стоит ли вообще пробовать сразу устроиться на работу или лучше все-таки пойти в университет?

Я понимаю, что вопрос не попадает под правила сообщества, но мне банально больше не к кому обратиться с этим вопросом, так что, пожалуйста, дайте ему повисеть 1-2 дня, чтобы кто-то успел мне ответить, а уже потом повесьте статус [закрыт].

Comment: Если Вы сейчас пойдете работать, то станете заурядным кодером, которых миллионы и которым цена медный грош за пучок в базарный день. Чтобы стать разработчиком нужно иметь университетское базовое математическое образование за первые три курса. Поэтому правильный путь - поступать в хороший вуз с хорошей математикой, первые три года только учиться, а после третьего курса начинать работать программистом за деньги, не бросая учебы.

Comment: Не валяй дурака. Готовься к экзаменам и поступай в универ. А программировать можешь на досуге. Когда пару-тройку курсов закончишь с хорошими оценками, то твоя зачетка начнет работать на тебя, и сможешь тогда подыскивать работу или для начала стажировку.

Comment: Какие-то тролли с завидной регулярностью выкладывают здесь такие вопросы типа от имени школьников. Только вот зачем?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Довольно спорное утверждение. Многим конечно образование нужно. Но все таки не всем. Невозможно сказать, как будет лучше конкретному человеку

Comment: @pepsicoca1, впервые за полгода вижу подобный вопрос по Unity, о каких троллях речь?

Comment: В 17 на работу вас никто не возьмет, да и работодателям нужны программисты, а не "школьные отличники".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Не конкретно вопрос по Unity, а вопросы типа "я школьник мне ХХ лет хочу заниматься программированием посоветуйте..." и дальше просьба что-то посоветовать и обязательно фраза что он не хочет учиться в институте. Зачем такие вбросы непонятно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, а почему вы на 100% уверены, что это "вброс, ложь и провокация"?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я не уверен, да и расследование проводить нет желания. Но то, что такие бессмысленные посты от имени школьников появляются здесь регулярно наводит на нехорошие мысли. Не далее как пару месяцев назад был пост типа от школьника 13 лет. Ну скажите, кто в 13 лет полезет на взрослый сайт спрашивать о программировании? :-(

Comment: @pepsicoca1 "пруфов нет, но осуждаю". Пусть задают хоть миллиард вопросов таких - потом все равно их закроют и 0 проблем. А так глядишь пару людей на путь истинный поставят.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker [пару людей на путь истинный поставят] Наверное я безнадежный циник, но мне все-таки кажется что такие (эти) вопросы задают не реальные люди а тролли. А сообщество тут перед ними распинается.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, "сообщество распинается", ну вы сейчас тоже тратите время просто потому что вы всех таких людей считаете троллями.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я же не пост сделал а всего лишь комментарий. Да к тому же комментарий к посту, который скоро удалят. Высказал некоторые сомнения в реальности существования таких "школьников". И сомнения, связанные с регулярностью появления таких постов. Вот и все, а дальше модераторы пусть думают кто тут диссертацию по психологии программистов пишет на материале SO.

Comment: В предыдущей компании, где я работал мы взяли джуном парня 17 лет, который учился в вечерней школе. Спокойно работает вот уже год, получает опыт) качается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот вопрос противоречит правилам ресурса(слишком общий). Но я считаю его хорошим и, пожалуй, все же отвечу на него. Может, не совсем так, как ты хочешь, но это тебе должно быть полезно.

Я бы сказал что существует множество путей. Но пару я хотел бы выделить как оптимальные (по моему мнению, на обьективность не ручаюсь). Есть так же и другие пути.

## Путь: Универ

1. В универе ты получишь знания которые напрямую пригодятся в программировании. Например, по физике или математике.
2. Если ты учишся в достаточно хорошем универе с хорошим именем - тебя охотнее возьмут на работу. По крайней мере твое резюме будет выделятся среди других резюме начинаючих кодеров.
3. По нужным предметам вкалываешь как никогда до этого. Остальные -- главное не завалить, а на оценки пофиг.
4. На втором или третьем идешь работать переводясь на заочку (обязательно нужно что бы на факультете таковая имелась). Желательно сразу в большую компанию. Желательно через знакомых, если таковые имеются. Ясен пень что без знаний тебя не возьмут чисто по знакомству.

Минус:

- Если нету знаний - корочка тебя не спасет.
- От тебя будут требовать получать кучу вообще ненужных знаний
- Никто не гарантирует что тебя будут обучать хорошие специалисты по профильным предметам. Не важен размер и распиаренность универа.

> Например в Киевском Политехе ректор и его приближенные запрещали ставить вышки 4G - боялись облучения радиоволнами... В ГЛАВНОМ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОМ УНИВЕРСИТЕТЕ СТРАНЫ. Фейсбук экс-президента одного из мобильных операторов: https://www.facebook.com/peter.chernyshov/posts/10222735827855507 чтиво более чем занятное.

> Или мне препод в универе(тот же КПИ) втирал что рисование блоксхем это ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНАЯ часть работы любого программиста. А это Киевский политех... Что такие преподаватели могут научить? А таких большинство.

Плюс:

- у тебя будет корочка
- вместе с лишними знаниями получаешь кучу полезных нейронных связей в мозгу которые помогают обучатся в общем и целом.
- Все же есть некий шанс что тебе попадется талантливый специалист работающий по профилю и паралельно преподающий в университете, который реально облегчит тебе жизнь в обучении и убережет тебя от множества ошибок. А такой шанс многого стоит.
- ВАЖНО: *никто не отбирает у тебя шанс самообучаться по нужным направлениям паралельно до универа.(про это ниже будет)*
- ВАЖНО: *если ты будешь умышленно копать в этом направлении - у тебя есть реальный шанс стать студентом по-обмену и поехать в другую страну на обучение и возможную работу.* Главное учась - копать в эту сторону!!! Если будешь сидеть на попе ровно - никто тебе этого не предложит, даже.

---

## Путь: без универа

1. Сам изучаешь английский, математику, физику, автоматизацию, алгоритмы. Можешь готовится по лекциям из Стэнфорда по выбранному направлению - они разделены по курсах/факультетах. Они в свободном доступе и они реально прекрасны. Я не верю что в любом универе СНГ ты можешь получить на столько свежий и качественный материал.
2. Получаешь сертификацию по тому направлению, которое тебя интересует. Она должна быть международной или же от компании которая напрямую связана с этим направлением - это практически гарантирует что ты станешь ценным специалистом. (но вообще стоит разузнать на сколько эта конкретная сертификация на рынке ценится, мало ли) Если по какой-то причине не существует по тому направлению, берешь сертификацию по ближайших направлениях к нужной. Или меняешь выбор сферы в сторону, где такая сертификация есть.
3. Находишь работу. У тебя есть более чем достаточная база и прекрасные сноски в резюме, за которые зацепится глаз HR-ов буквально гарантированно. 18-19-летний парень с международной сертификацией - это редкость.

Минус:

- Тебе лично очень сложно оценивать когда ты готов. Смотри в википедию на "эфект даннинга-крюгера"
- **КРИТИЧЕСКИ велика вероятность что ты не осилишь. У большинства на такое мотивации и самодисциплины банально не хватит.** Тем более ее нет в 17 лет. Как говориться, думаешь что ты Лев Толстой, а на деле... вобщем, многие в молодом возрасте сильно себя переоценивают - юношеский максимализм это нормально.
- **велика вероятность что ты выберешь неправильное направление развития и пойдешь в совсем левые дебри потратив кучу времени ВПУСТУЮ.**
- В европе и развитых странах ты -- никто. Там нужна корочка. И она влияет на зарплату.
- Не забывай про армию

Плюсы:

- Не тратишь лишнего времени. Изучаешь только то что тебе нужно. (если правильно выберешь стратегию, что не факт)
- Получаешь практический опыт и навычки уже здесь и сейчас не тратя времени на полную чепуху.
- сертификация международная или сертификация от официального представителя направления -- это лучше и важнее чем универ. Универ не дает гарантии знаний. А вот сертификация высокого уровня в сфере -- дает.
- проработав в 4-5 больших компаниях подряд на больших проэктах -- всем будет пофиг что у тебя нету корочки. Что здесь, что за рубежом. **Но это ЕСЛИ.** И достаточно большое. "Если", которое напрямую зависит от твоей целеустремленности.

---

## Вывод:

И там и там есть свои плюсы и свои минусы. И там и там есть риски. В любом случае все зависит напрямую от тебя и от умения себя РАЦИОНАЛЬНО оценивать.

Лично я бы лучше возвратился во времени и пробовал бы без универа, чем просрать столько жизни. Жаль, только, что это невозможно.

Я считаю что универ обязателен только для отдельных очень узких професий, куда без корочки не пробратся -- например медицина. Программирование, к счастью, к таким направлениям не относится. Тебя будут принимать за знания, а не за корочку.

**Но если ты выберешь путь без универа и испортишь жизнь себе - меня виноватым не делай. Это твой личный выбор. И риски все на тебе. А если ты не уверен в своей целеустремленности и усидчивости - риски ОЧЕНЬ высоки.** Это, всего лишь, мое личное мнение, а не гарантированный и доказанный факт.

PS: Я знаком с очень талантливыми айтишниками которые добились успеха имея образование повара и эколога, например. Моего брата сейчас забирает любой ААА проэкт как горячие пирожки на баснословные для меня деньги. А его выгнали после 3 курса универа за неуспеваемость. Это, даже, не бакалавр. Но у него такой список бывших работ в резюме, которому многие с корочкой позавидуют. Он со второго курса пошел работать над первым "сталкером", следующие проэкты в резюме были не хуже :)

А так же знаком и с полными бездарями имеющими полное техническое образование (в т.ч. красный диплом по профилю программирования), которые шли продавать телики в ближайший супермаркет после выпуска. Универ тебе ничего не гарантирует.

И последнее: заводи знакомства с людьми из сферы. Они и помочь могут и вообще социальные связи -- это важно.

> **Интересный факт:** Уверяю что универ будет пытатся впаривать кучу лапши и золотые горы. Что, вероятнее всего, не так на самом деле. Они заинтересованы в студентах ибо каждый студент, в т.ч. бютжетный - это деньги.
>
> Например, ректор моего факультета на вступительной лекции для потока(где были студенты и много родителей) утверждал что ВСЕ по окончанию обучения на этом факультете получают работу по специальности и что есть документальные подтверждения и любой желающий может пойти в такой-то кабинет и проверить лично.
>
> По выпуску же... С меня требовали бумажку с конкретным текстом. Уже деталей не помню, но звучать дожно было приблизительно так: "Справка о том, что %ФИО% принят на работу по своей специальности в компанию %название компании%"" эта бумажка должна была быть оформлена абсолютно любым работодателем и заверена печатью или подписью директора компании. Без этой бумажки диплом НЕ ОТДАВАЛИ. Прошу заметить, что компания может быть хоть "пятерочка"/"АТБ", а позиция хоть "продавец". А какая специальность у человека на факультете -- вообще не играет роли. Им главное иметь документальное подтверждение в виде бумажки на которой будет написано что ты работаешь по специальности. Для статистики. Как перед начальством в универе, так и перед родителями.
> Не думаю что это законно, но, вероятнее всего, у них есть лазейки как выкрутится. И уверяю, что в каждом универе будут подобные хитрости.

Comment: Прошение к минусящим: не стесняйтесь, коментируйте с чем именно не согласны.

Comment: Привет, можно поподробнее узнать про сертификацию, что такое и с чем едят?

Comment: + 1 за `просрать столько жизни` хД

Comment: @froxxendsg получение сертификата о твоем профиле. Вот например, есть продукт под названием 1с. У компании-производителя есть курсы по 1с, а так же сертификация после экзамена на знания. У майкрсофт есть сертификация на знания серверных ос, на знания MSSQL и на кучу других штук. Это как примеры частных сертификатов от производителя некоего продукта. В случае с английским - сертификация IELTS. В случае с тестировщиками -- ISTQB сертификация. Это как примеры международных сертификаций. Ищи по нужным тебе профилям.

Comment: @froxxendsg я немного проапдейтил ответ.

Comment: Поставил минус: в ответе явный хейт универа и слишком лояльное отношение к самообразованию. "Я хочу делать игры на Unity" - это не "цель". Судя по ответам, автор вопроса даже загуглить некоторые вещи не может, что абсолютно нормально для не обученного подростка. Сертификаты - это, конечно, круто, но сертификат Unity - это фарс: никому не нужен, его наличие == заученная (и то поверхностно) документация без практических навыков. Также универ учит **самостоятельно** решать проблемы, а не просить совета. И кстати образование "повара или эколога" - это все равно показатель **хотя бы** усидчивости.

Comment: Не хейт. Просто я прошел через политех и обьективной полезности не вижу. Это говорит просто мой опыт. Я ни разу никого не отговаривал от универа. Даже наоборот, советовал людям пойти учится, а потом уже на работу и заочку. Но их я знал, и знал что им не хватит усидчивости. Здесь автора я не знаю. И я просто выложил за и против обеих сторон про которые полезно было бы знать, по моему скромному мнению. И кстате, заметь что в пути "без универа" я посоветовал лекции.... УНИВЕРА -- Оксфорда. Какой жэ это хейт универа получается?) Это твои фантазии.

Comment: @Andrew **А людей которые говорят "универ обязателен" я воспринимаю как людей, которые просрали 5 лет жизни и хотят что бы все остальные сделали так же**, "пошел в универ - просрал 5 лет" =/= хейт? Да хоть чью лекции посоветуйте, сути это не поменяет. Скажу по секрету, бакалавриат особо то и не ставит цели кого-то чему-то научить, он скорее учить распределять время, общаться с людьми и справляться с задачами самостоятельно, а не спрашивать в интернетах "а что же мне делать??".

Comment: Сам прошел через технический универ, сам долго упирался и говорил, что это трата времени, скажу ли я это сейчас? Едва ли, матан в геймдеве на каждом шагу, устройство железа пк и в целом всей это экосистемы тоже на каждом шагу в айти, если мы не говорим про верстальщиков. Кстати насчет **лекций**, сколько там часов этих лекций? Тысячи? Уже, наверное, и до десятка тысяч недалеко, их в каком порядке смотреть? Вы автору составите программу или мы увидим здесь еще с десяток вопросов "я не пошел в универ, а как мне теперь учиться"?

Comment: То есть если мнение НЕ такое же как у тебя, то это сразу хейт? Может мне начать рассказывать что ты фетишируешь на универы в ответ? Это не хейт. Просто я считаю его НЕ обязательным. Ни больше, ни меньше. Если бы он хотел в европу или США - я бы посоветовал бы ему идти в универ. Не потому что этот вариант лучше, а потому что этот вариант выгоднее в конкретных условиях.

Comment: На тему лекций... Все как с универом. `Выбор общей професии/факультета => выбор направления /кафедры => лекции по профильным предметам [последней версии из доступных]`.. Ничем от универа не отличается просто потому, что это и есть лекции универа/кафедры/предмета. Так же саму программу никто не скрывает вообще. Можно и посмотреть что за чем учить. Я, даже теоретически,  не понимаю почему у тебя возник вопрос в каком порядке смотреть лекции.

Comment: "**просрать** 5 лет" и "я считаю его не обязательным" - разные вещи

Comment: Давай еще раз когда универ обязательный: обязательный универ если: хочется работать за границей и начинать работать там достаточно рано; Если профессия требует "корочки" (например медицина или хим.производство) ; если нету возможности обойти армию; Если недостаточно самодисциплины или мотивации; Может быть что-то забыл, но это точно основные.

Comment: но в остальных случаях универ это -- просирание 5 лет жизни. Если самодисциплины у человека достаточно - то это ничто иное как просирание времени. Ибо ты можешь это же время потратить на развитие себя в НУЖНЫХ профильных дисциплинах глубже, чем если бы ты это делал в универе. И это время ты можешь потратить ВЫГОДНЕЕ получая ПРАКТИЧЕСКИЙ опыт, который важнее теоретического универного. А там, все таки, больше теоретический опыт, чем практический. **И заметь! То что должна быть самодисциплина на уровне я выделил жирным текстом в своем ответе.**

Comment: Если ты не согласен с этим утверждением, обьясни мне почему ты считаешь что лишнее время потраченное на профильные предметы это хуже чем это же время потраченное на НЕ профильные предметы/дорогу в универ/экзамены? Почему деньги потраченные на жилье/книги/канцелярию/тетради в универе это более выгодное вложение в "корочку" чем деньги потраченные на узкопрофильную сертификацию?

Comment: А давай теперь подумаем, может ли человек в 17 лет, который **не знает, что ему дальше делать**, адекватно определить, хватит ли ему дисциплины? Если **для тебя** матан, линал, оси и другие относящиеся к геймдеву вещи - просирание 5 лет жизни - окей, ты прав, универ ненужная помойка. Мне кстати очень интересно, как ты так судишь о жизни без универа, не попробовав ее на своей шкуре :)

Comment: Ну, как минимум, мой брат у универе так и не доучился, как я писал в тексте. Он ушел то ли отучившись 3 курса то ли не закончив 3й курс. Не уверен считается ли это "без универа" или нет. Да и, снова таки, есть знакомые айтишники которые стали айтишниками закончив вообще НЕ технические специальности(про что я тоже писал в тексте). Это уже можно считать "без универа" по моему мнению. Что было это обучение, что его не было - на знания в IT сфере это обучение не повлияло ровным счетом никак.

Comment: Нет, нельзя, вышка - это вышка, айти или нет, практически везде учат основам матана и другим полезным для мозга наукам. Также универ учит работать с людьми и информацией. Если ты уверен, что в 17 лет человек пускай теоретически в вакууме может понимать, чего он хочет и быть дисциплинированным - окей, не вижу смысла спорить.

Comment: Ты, наверное, не видел как люди учатся на вышке в большинстве универов. Знаний может быть полный ноль, даже, в профильных предметах, не говоря уже об непрофильных. Зато диплом на руках. Ты исходишь из аксиомы что люди получая вышку реально учились, но это практически наверняка не так. Посмотри на людей вокруг -- большинство людей с вышкой не могут решить банальные математические задачи за 7-8мой клас - чисто ради интереса повтори мой эксперимент и позадавай задачи своим знакомым. О чем ты говоришь? Такое чувство что мы с тобой на разных планетах обитаем.